# How to include location when uploading photo?

Tags: python, django, api, instagram

I'm using InstagramApi.

This is my Python code:

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI

InstagramAPI = InstagramAPI("username", "password")
InstagramAPI.login()  # login

photo_path = '/home/user/image/index.jpeg'
caption = "Sample photo"
location = "Rome"
InstagramAPI.uploadPhoto(photo_path, caption=caption, location=location)
```

Without location it works... how can I post with location?

It seems there's no official documentation... please help.

Comment: The InstagramAPI library is an unoffiical library for insta interfacing, hence the function `def uploadPhoto(self, photo, caption=None, upload_id=None, is_sidecar=None)`, has limited capability
So in order to send your location data you need to tweak the original uploadPhoto function and use it in your program
location of the function is in `https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python/blob/master/InstagramAPI/InstagramAPI.py`

Comment: Also, since native Instagram API is deprecated, you would like to use Instagram Graph API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started, for your project.

Comment: @nishant-patel do you know if the instagram graph api you referenced is able to get lat/long from a post (or media id)?